# What chore can be easily done with cake, but is a pain to do with Powershell + MSBuild?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, cakebuild

When I need to orchestrate a build I write one or more Powershell scripts that invoke MSBuild to actually build the code.

I am very familiar with both Powershell and MSBuild, so it seems painless to me. However, I am curious about Cake and would like to see if there is something it does easily which would be a pain to do with Powershell + MSBuild.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of the Cake project.

Cake is a build orchestrator, and therefore not a direct replacement of MsBuild, which you can also use for orchestrating your builds, but also is a build tool.

Main difference between PowerShell and MsBuild and Cake is, that with Cake you write your build orchestration scripts in C# (while you can also write C# in PowerShell or MsBuild scripts, Cake is built on top of Roslyn and therefore C# is a first class citizen). Cake also provides a DSL which simplifies common tasks and execution of tools (like MsBuild).

Like PowerShell and MsBuild, Cake is open source and cross-platform.

Comment: Right, but I am using powershell to orchestrate and msbuild to build the actual code. I was wondering if you could give an example of something that is painful in powershell+msbuild (I do not consider powershell and msbuild separately, only as a pair), but is pain free in cake. I need to understand why would one consider replacing powershell+msbuild with cake.

Comment: This really depends on your personal preferences and Stackoverflow is not the best place to discuss these kind of stuff. If you have specific questions how something can be done in PowerShell, MsBuild or Cake please ask these specific questions otherwise I would suggest that you try out the different solutions to find out what best fits your needs and personal preferences.

Comment: I reworded my question to ask a question. Unfortunately, it is not very concrete, but the answer can be.

Comment: As said, in the end it depends on your preferences and Stackoverflow is not the place to discuss about opinions. If PowerShell / MsBuild works for you then stick with it. If you prefer to write your build orchestration scripts in C# instead of PowerShell give Cake a try. Also Cake is more comparable to something like Psake than plain PowerShell.